Pino Transport streams not working with the pino.transport function, only with the pino() constructor
Pino Transports working fine with this
export const masterLogger = pino({
    level: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINO_LOG_LEVEL ?? "debug"}`, // NOTE IF YOU NEED TO SEE LOGS SET TO DEBUG SHOWS UP IN CHROME CONSOLE. ONCE IN DEV ENVIRONMENT SHOULD ROUTE TO AZURE DB FOR LOGGING
    redact: ['email', 'profileName', 'password', 'address'],
    //timestamp: () => `",timestamp":"${new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()}"`,

    transport: {
        target: 'pino-pretty',
        options: {
            colorize: true,
        },
    },
});

When I modify the file to make use of the pino.transport file like the following:
const transport = pino.transport({
    target: 'pino-pretty',
        options: {
            colorize: true,
        },
  });

export const masterLogger = pino({
    level: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PINO_LOG_LEVEL ?? "debug"}`, // NOTE IF YOU NEED TO SEE LOGS SET TO DEBUG SHOWS UP IN CHROME CONSOLE. ONCE IN DEV ENVIRONMENT SHOULD ROUTE TO AZURE DB FOR LOGGING
    redact: ['email', 'profileName', 'password', 'address'],
    //timestamp: () => `",timestamp":"${new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()}"`,
    /*transport: {
        target: 'pino-mongodb',
        options: {
            uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
            database: process.env.MONGODB_DATABASE_NAME,
            collection: 'app_logs',
            level: 'debug',
        },
    },*/
    transport: transport,
});


we get this error:
TypeError: pino__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).transport is not a function
then to try to resolve this, if I add this import to the top of my logger.js file
import 'pino-pretty';
I get
Module not found: Can't resolve 'worker_threads'
Not sure why this is, please any explanation will help.

Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is almost entirely composed of tags, which should not be in the title at all. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know exactly what it's about. For suggestions on writing a good title, see the [help].
